# What's a good way to deploy and update a long running process?

Tags: deployment

I have a process running on a server.

FYI I'm trying to solve the same problem for both nodejs and Python - I don't really think the specific server/languages matters as the question is more about approach to deployment.

The work the the process does might take anywhere from seconds to hours to run.

I'm trying to work out how to deploy updated code for the process.

I don't want to just stop the process in the middle of what it is doing for fear of losing all the work done so far in the long running process.

So what's a good way to get the process to gracefully exit and restart when new code has arrived?

I use systemd for running the nodejs service.

I use Ansible to deploy updates, not that this is really relevant.

I thought maybe at the end of each execution of the long running process the server could check to see if some file has been placed on the disk as some sort of flag to indicate it should exit and restart, but that seems kinda brittle and hacky.

Anyone got any better mechanisms for this sort of thing?